# Disable ES6 only in Razor Views?

Tags: visual-studio, ecmascript-6, resharper

Since I am using webpack with babel, I enabled ES6 Features for my solution.
This works fine for Javascript Modules.

However, in my Razor Views I am using some inline scripts:

```
<script>
    var foo = function() {
        var bar = 'baz';
        alert(bar);
    }
</script>
```

Now since I have enabled Ecmascript 2015, if I reformat my Code (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>), the following happens:

```
<script>
    var foo = function() {
        const bar = 'baz';
        alert(bar);
    }
</script>
```

Of course some browser from a company named Microsoft immediatelly complains about `const`.

So is it possible to enable ES6 Features only in JS files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be supported at the moment.

As workaround to the direct problem, I have created a custom Code Cleanup setting:

[image: Code Cleanup]

I also created an Issue here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-469231